# How to create a vector with non-copyable and non-assignable objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, noncopyable

I have a class

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int x): x_(x) {}
  void SetValue(int m) {x_=m};
 private:
   DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(A);
};
```

I'm trying to create a vector of objects of type A

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> objects;
objects.reserve(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   auto a = MakeUnique<A>();
   a->SetValue(20);
   objects.emplace_back(a);
}
```

This results in a compilation error call to deleted constructor of `'std::unique_ptr<A, std::default_delete<A> >'`

Comment: `DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(A)` should not be a macro that defines the copy ctor and assign operator, it should be a base class that mark the copy and assign operator as deleted, and defaulting move operations.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, while I always drive from boost noncopyable, I fail to see the advantage of your assertion / axiom above the macro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, so you need to move it into the container:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   auto a = MakeUnique<A>();
   a->SetValue(20);
   objects.emplace_back(std::move(a));
}
```

Comment: Possible alternative with C++17: `auto & a = objects.emplace_back(MakeUnique<A>()); a->SetValue(20);`

Comment: `objects.emplace_back(MakeUnique<A>()); objects.back()->SetValue(20);`

Comment: @Xirema While equivalent in this case, in general it would have different behaviour for cases where `SetValue` can throw an exception. I generally prefer to fully set up objects before handing them over to a contaier.

Comment: @RustyX See my previous comment: equivalent in this case, different when exceptions are possible.